# Import html string on a different file on react. Using prismjs to display code highlighting

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, prismjs

Using Prismjs to display code snippets in a design system.

I want to separate the html code sample in a standalone file and import it into my component.

Code sample Component:

**CodeSampleContainer.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Prism from "prismjs";
import './CodeSample.scss';
import '../Shared/prism.css';

// Import separate html file
import { html } './htmlSnippet.jsx';

class CodeSample extends Component {
  hasHtmlBlob() {
    return (
      <pre>
        <code className="language-html">
          {html} // Any html displayed here will be highlighted by prism
        </code>
      </pre>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="CodeSample"> 
        {this.hasHtmlBlob()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

HTML that i want to export:

**htmlSnippet.jsx**

```
const html = `
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>`

return html;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two problems in your code:

### JSX syntax

Instead of declaring your template as a string, you should do it on "react way"

```
const html = (
    <div>
        <ul>
           <li>1</li>
           <li>2</li>
           <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

### Export missing

If you want to export your template from your `htmlSnippet.jsx`, you should use `export`, not `return`.

```
export { html };
```

Comment: Im having issues when I try to display {html}. It comes back as [object object]